# Svg image on blazor showing slow loading on localhost

Tags: html, css, svg, razor

I have an svg to be used on my blazor where loading is slow, the image is small it weighs about 4KB.

This slowdown only happens when I call the svg file in an image element

If I put the svg code directly, the loading is extremely fast.

But to keep code clean I prefer to use the svg file, is there any way to make this load faster?

**Code that loads slowly:**

```
<div>
  <img srcset="imgs/mysvgtest.svg"/>
</div>
```

**Code that has fast loading:**

```
<div>
   <svg>
     <g>
      ...
     </g>
   </svg>
</div>
```

MySvg Test

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="2500" height="2500" viewBox="0 0 192.756 192.756">
    <g fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd">
        <path fill="#fff" d="M0 0h192.756v192.756H0V0z"/>
        <path d="M37.624 101.055c0 11.686-3.715 23.734-17.395 23.734S2.834 112.74 2.834 101.055c0-11.688 3.714-23.828 17.395-23.828 13.68 0 17.395 12.14 17.395 23.828zm-22.016 0c0 2.627.182 12.32 4.621 12.32s4.62-9.693 4.62-12.32c0-2.629-.181-12.322-4.62-12.322s-4.621 9.693-4.621 12.322zM55.909 85.2h.182c1.721-4.349 5.617-7.973 10.6-7.973 9.422 0 8.607 10.509 8.607 17.123v29.533H62.523V98.789c0-2.355.906-8.697-3.171-8.697-2.899 0-3.443 2.989-3.443 5.254v28.536H43.135v-45.75h12.774V85.2zM94.311 50.774v73.109H81.537V50.774h12.774zM113.244 78.133v45.75h-12.773v-45.75h12.773zM98.748 64.454c0-4.62 3.715-8.063 8.336-8.063 4.439 0 7.881 3.896 7.881 8.244 0 4.349-3.715 8.063-8.152 8.063-4.44 0-8.065-3.715-8.065-8.244zM132.27 85.2h.182c1.721-4.349 5.617-7.973 10.6-7.973 9.422 0 8.607 10.509 8.607 17.123v29.533h-12.775V98.789c0-2.355.906-8.697-3.17-8.697-2.898 0-3.443 2.989-3.443 5.254v28.536h-12.773v-45.75h12.773V85.2h-.001zM189.605 104.406h-20.201c.09 3.352-.092 10.6 4.801 10.6 3.262 0 4.076-2.537 4.076-5.256h10.871c-1.086 8.426-5.162 15.039-14.494 15.039-12.955 0-17.576-11.506-17.576-22.83 0-10.961 3.986-24.732 17.305-24.732 8.424 0 16.217 7.52 15.492 21.923l-.274 5.256zm-10.779-8.969c0-2.989-.635-8.425-4.621-8.425-3.896 0-4.711 5.254-4.711 8.153v1.358h9.332v-1.086zM3.753 129.209h185.601v12.773H3.753v-12.773z"/>
        <path fill="#fff" d="M7.424 130.76v9.484H5.55v-9.484h1.874zM10.808 130.76l2.339 5.723.025-.025a5.977 5.977 0 0 1-.15-1.434v-4.264h1.874v9.484h-1.773l-2.314-5.723-.025.023.088.957.012.391v4.352H9.01v-9.484h1.798zM20.824 130.76v1.761H19.34v7.723h-1.874v-7.723h-1.472v-1.761h4.83zM25.705 130.76v1.761h-1.9v2.063h1.673v1.76h-1.673v2.138h1.925v1.762h-3.799v-9.484h3.774zM27.114 140.244v-9.484H29c1.195 0 3.333.127 3.333 2.717 0 1.045-.416 1.938-1.346 2.453l1.647 4.314h-1.975l-1.647-4.377h-.025v4.377h-1.873zm1.874-5.408l.327.012c.855 0 1.194-.578 1.194-1.359 0-.678-.327-1.23-1.27-1.182h-.251v2.529zM35.832 130.76l2.34 5.723.024-.025a5.977 5.977 0 0 1-.151-1.434v-4.264h1.874v9.484h-1.773l-2.314-5.723-.025.023.088.957.013.391v4.352h-1.874v-9.484h1.798zM45.269 130.76v1.761h-1.9v2.063h1.673v1.76h-1.673v2.138h1.924v1.762h-3.797v-9.484h3.773zM51.03 130.76v1.761h-1.484v7.723h-1.874v-7.723H46.2v-1.761h4.83zM59.081 130.76l2.276 9.484h-2l-.352-1.598h-1.899l-.34 1.598h-1.861l2.201-9.484h1.975zm-.831 3.873l-.214-1.434h-.025l-.201 1.434-.402 2.529h1.32l-.478-2.529zM62.365 140.244v-9.484h1.886c1.194 0 3.333.127 3.333 2.717 0 1.045-.415 1.938-1.346 2.453l1.647 4.314h-1.974l-1.648-4.377h-.025v4.377h-1.873zm1.874-5.408l.327.012c.855 0 1.195-.578 1.195-1.359 0-.678-.327-1.23-1.271-1.182h-.252v2.529h.001zM69.284 140.244v-9.484h1.836c.73 0 1.359.025 1.962.516.628.504.968 1.346.968 2.139 0 .842-.314 1.484-1.019 1.961.78.379 1.17 1.385 1.17 2.201 0 1.875-1.384 2.668-3.094 2.668h-1.823v-.001zm1.874-4.139v2.566c.755.037 1.195-.516 1.195-1.309 0-.741-.453-1.282-1.195-1.257zm0-3.773v2.314c.705 0 1.119-.479 1.119-1.195 0-.691-.402-1.156-1.119-1.119zM79.333 130.76v1.761h-1.899v2.063h1.673v1.76h-1.673v2.138h1.925v1.762H75.56v-9.484h3.773zM82.617 130.76v9.484h-1.874v-9.484h1.874zM88.554 130.76v1.761H87.07v7.723h-1.874v-7.723h-1.471v-1.761h4.829zM93.56 132.898c-.376-.328-.842-.604-1.358-.604-.579 0-.943.352-.943.93 0 1.561 2.854 1.648 2.854 4.213 0 1.686-.968 2.957-2.729 2.957-.527 0-1.182-.164-1.609-.479v-1.785c.44.301.868.502 1.421.502.604 0 1.082-.402 1.082-1.031 0-.729-.578-1.006-1.107-1.383-1.082-.73-1.749-1.434-1.749-2.818 0-1.496.868-2.791 2.479-2.791.604 0 1.144.164 1.659.465v1.824zM101.537 134.961v.742c0 2.012-.49 4.691-3.043 4.691-2.554 0-3.384-2.742-3.384-4.842 0-2.189.705-4.943 3.384-4.943 1.445 0 2.389.904 2.791 2.252l-1.822.703c-.09-.479-.24-1.219-.957-1.219-1.271-.076-1.396 2.264-1.396 3.156 0 .98.062 3.156 1.447 3.156.955 0 1.105-1.283 1.105-1.936h-1.193v-1.762h3.068v.002zM102.785 140.244v-9.484h1.887c1.195 0 3.334.127 3.334 2.717 0 1.045-.416 1.938-1.346 2.453l1.646 4.314h-1.975l-1.646-4.377h-.025v4.377h-1.875zm1.875-5.408l.326.012c.855 0 1.195-.578 1.195-1.359 0-.678-.326-1.23-1.27-1.182h-.252v2.529h.001zM111.529 130.76v6.139c0 .717-.09 1.799.93 1.799.918 0 .918-.693.932-1.396v-6.541h1.873v6.918c0 1.006-.113 2.717-2.816 2.717-1.748 0-2.793-.818-2.793-2.592v-7.043h1.874v-.001zM116.801 140.244v-9.484h1.951c.402 0 3.219-.252 3.219 2.805 0 1.773-1.145 2.793-2.881 2.793l-.414-.025v3.912h-1.875v-.001zm1.875-5.433c.906.037 1.422-.303 1.422-1.271 0-.678-.266-1.232-1.07-1.232h-.352v2.503zM123.18 140.244v-9.484h1.949c.402 0 3.221-.252 3.221 2.805 0 1.773-1.145 2.793-2.881 2.793l-.416-.025v3.912h-1.873v-.001zm1.873-5.433c.906.037 1.422-.303 1.422-1.271 0-.678-.264-1.232-1.068-1.232h-.354v2.503zM133.33 130.76v1.761h-1.898v2.063h1.672v1.76h-1.672v2.138h1.923v1.762h-3.798v-9.484h3.773zM138.074 140.244v-9.484h1.887c1.193 0 3.332.127 3.332 2.717 0 1.045-.414 1.938-1.346 2.453l1.648 4.314h-1.975l-1.648-4.377h-.025v4.377h-1.873zm1.873-5.408l.328.012c.855 0 1.193-.578 1.193-1.359 0-.678-.326-1.23-1.27-1.182h-.252v2.529h.001zM148.766 130.76v1.761h-1.899v2.063h1.672v1.76h-1.672v2.138h1.924v1.762h-3.799v-9.484h3.774zM152.049 130.76v9.484h-1.873v-9.484h1.873zM157.986 130.76v1.761h-1.484v7.723h-1.873v-7.723h-1.473v-1.761h4.83zM160.967 130.76v3.711h1.9v-3.711h1.873v9.484h-1.873v-4.014h-1.9v4.014h-1.873v-9.484h1.873zM169.938 130.76l2.277 9.484h-2l-.352-1.598h-1.9l-.338 1.598h-1.861l2.199-9.484h1.975zm-.831 3.873l-.213-1.434h-.025l-.201 1.434-.402 2.529h1.32l-.479-2.529zM175.098 130.76v7.722h1.961v1.762h-3.836v-9.484h1.875zM180.041 130.76v7.722h1.961v1.762h-3.836v-9.484h1.875zM186.883 130.76v1.761h-1.901v2.063h1.674v1.76h-1.674v2.138h1.926v1.762h-3.799v-9.484h3.774z"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Can you put a snippet up with the SVG included as I don't think we're going to find the problem without.

Comment: @AHaworth svg code add

Comment: Using just the code you have shown and writing the SVG to a file I see instant response both if served locally and if served across the internet from my webhost.

Comment: but on blazor it doesn't happen if I use an svg file the loading takes time and it's noticeable

Comment: Could you put up a snippet which shows the problem somehow?